# connect Azure Service Management with python sdk

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, sdk, azure-service-fabric

I'm using this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management.
I'm doing exact what they wrote in the guide and I keep getting error message.

```
>>> from azure import *
>>> from azure.servicemanagement import *
>>> subscription_id = '************************'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile(r'c:\key\mycert.pem')
True
>>> certificate_path = r'c:\key\mycert.pem'
>>> sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, certificate_path)
>>> result = sms.list_locations()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementservice.py", line 1131, in list_locations
Locations)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementclient.py", line 365, in _perform_get
response = self.perform_get(path, x_ms_version)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementclient.py", line 175, in perform_get
response = self._perform_request(request)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementclient.py", line 339, in _perform_request
return _management_error_handler(ex)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementclient.py", line 419, in _management_error_handler
return _general_error_handler(http_error)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicemanagement\_common_error.py", line 34, in _general_error_handler
raise AzureHttpError(message, http_error.status)
azure.common.AzureHttpError: Forbidden
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>ForbiddenError</Code><Message>The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.</Message></Error>
```

I've uploaded the mycert.cer to a cloud service in my azure portal.
someone have an idea why the problem is?
I'm sure that the pem and the cer files are ok.

Comment: One common reason I have seen with this 403 error and Service Management API is when a tool like Fiddler is running. Can you please check if that is not the case.

Comment: Any update or concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error information & the offical document of [`Service Management Status and Error Codes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460801.aspx), the issue reason as the error information said as below.

[image]

Per my experience, I think there are two reasons which will cause the issue.

1. The certificate you current used is invalid on Azure. Besides re-generate a new certificate refered to the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management), you also can follow the document of Azure SDK for Python about [`Using the Azure .PublishSettings certificate`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicemanagement.html#using-the-azure-publishsettings-certificate) to create the client certificate.

> **Using the Azure .PublishSettings certificate**
>
> You can download your Azure publish settings file and use the certificate that is embedded in that file to create the client certificate. The server certificate already exists, so you won’t need to upload one.

2. The server certificate file did not be uploaded into Azure Management portal settings, as below.

[image]

As reference, there is a [blog](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/25/consuming-windows-azure-service-management-api-in-java/) writed by @GauravMantri, which is very helpful for you, that introduced the steps in details alought it's for Java.

Hope it helps.